# residual network for a network with lower and upper bounds?

Tags: graphs, network-flow

How does one construct the residual network in such a case?

The formula is for edge $(u, v)$  is

$$rf(u,v) = (c_{\mathrm{upper}}(u,v) - f(u,v)) + (f(v,u) - c_{\mathrm{lower}}(v, u))\,,$$

where $rf(u, v)$ is the residual flow on the edge $(u, v)$, $c_{\mathrm{upper}}$ and $c_{\mathrm{lower}}$ are capacities on the edge and $f$ is the flow.

If, say, my edge $(u, v)$ has capacities $[3, 25]$ and a flow $f(u,v)=1$, then what are $rf(u, v)$ and $rf(v, u)$?

what is $c_{\mathrm{lower}}(v, u)$?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by residual flow here, I am assuming you are talking about network flow maximization problem. Residual capacities of edges are given by $\hat{c}_{lower}(u,v)=0$, $\hat{c}_{upper}(u,v) = c_{upper}(u,v) - f(u,v)$ for the forward edge and $\hat{c}_{lower}(v,u) = 0$, $\hat{c}_{upper}(v,u) = f(u,v)-c_{lower}(u,v)$ for the backward edge. This is the amount of flexibility we have in changing the flow on that edge, increase flow by sending flow on forward edge and decrease by sending on backward edge.

Comment: And the example you mentioned does not seem to be a valid flow, as flow in the edge is less than lower bound on the capacity.